# Can't get rid of mypy error about wrong type numpy.bool_ and bool

Tags: python, numpy, mypy

I have a classe containing several `np.array` :

```
class VECMParams(ModelParams):
    def __init__(
        self,
        ecm_gamma: np.ndarray,
        ecm_mu: Optional[np.ndarray],
        ecm_lambda: np.ndarray,
        ecm_beta: np.ndarray,
        intercept_coint: bool,
    ):
        self.ecm_gamma = ecm_gamma 
        self.ecm_mu = ecm_mu
        self.ecm_lambda = ecm_lambda 
        self.ecm_beta = ecm_beta
        self.intercept_coint = intercept_coint
```

I want to override `==` operator. Basically, a `VECMParam` is equal to another when all of their arrays are equal to `rhs` one :

```
def __eq__(self, rhs: object) -> bool:
    if not isinstance(rhs, VECMParams):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    return (
        np.all(self.ecm_gamma == rhs.ecm_gamma) and
        np.all(self.ecm_mu == rhs.ecm_mu) and
        np.all(self.ecm_lambda == rhs.ecm_lambda) and
        np.all(self.ecm_beta == rhs.ecm_beta) 
    )
```

Still, mypy keeps saying that `Incompatible return value type (got "Union[bool_, bool]", expected "bool") [return-value]` because `np.all` returns `bool_` and `__eq__` needs to return native `bool`. I search for hours it looks like there is no way to convert these bool_ to native bool. Anyone having the same problem ?

PS: doing `my_bool_ is True` is not evaluated to the right native bool value

Comment: If you want to check whether two arrays are equal, you should usually use [`numpy.array_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_equal.html) rather than `np.all(x == y)`. Also, if an operator overload doesn't understand how to interact with the other operand, it should `return NotImplemented`, not `raise NotImplementedError()`.

Comment: Thank you for the advices I didn't know :) Though, if I return NotImplemented, which is actually a None, __eq__ should return an Optional[bool] right ?

Comment: NotImplemented isn't None. It's its own special thing. Strangely, mypy has a special case for NotImplemented, so the return annotation should still be `bool`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [`numpy.all()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

```
A new boolean or array is returned unless out is specified, in which case a reference to out is returned.
```

This is the `Union[ndarray, bool]`.

How to fix:

```
def __eq__(self, rhs: 'VECMParams') -> bool:
    if not isinstance(rhs, VECMParams):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    return bool(
        np.all(self.ecm_gamma == rhs.ecm_gamma) and
        np.all(self.ecm_mu == rhs.ecm_mu) and
        np.all(self.ecm_lambda == rhs.ecm_lambda) and
        np.all(self.ecm_beta == rhs.ecm_beta) 
    )
```

Comment: Then how do you enforce that a np.array equals another (shape is the same and all elements are the same) and return a native bool instead of a bool_ ?

Comment: You can use this without `axis`, but result depends on types, shapes and additional parameters.
See examples in documentation:

```python
>>> np.all([[True,False],[True,True]], axis=0)
array([ True, False])
```

Possible return types are different.

Comment: And, of course, you can always use explicit type conversion: `bool(np.all(...))`.

Comment: This will give you "real bool" or `ValueError` if conversion is impossible.